# How long does it take for a page to be assigned Google page rank?

Tags: seo, google, pagerank

The home page of my website has been indexed by Google more than 6 months ago. Some of the internal pages have received a page rank 6 or higher, however, the page rank of the home page remains 0. What might be the reason and is there anything I can do about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A page is assigned PageRank as soon as it is indexed as all pages start off with a default PR (which I *think* is .15). However, that doesn't mean you'll see that PR in a toolbar or reporting tool. Public PR is updated only periodically so whatever PR you see via reporting tools is a snapshot of the ***past***. It does not reflect a page's current PR.

Keep in mind that toolbars and other reporting tools can be flawed and not reflect a page's proper PR. It's also possible that the home page has received a penalty for selling links or something similar. Do you sell links or advertising on your home page?

How does your home page rank in the SERPs? If it is doing well I wouldn't put too much energy into figuring this out. If it ranks poorly then there is an issue somewhere that needs to be addressed and you should find out what is causing your home page to behave mysteriously in the SERPs and with its PR.

Comment: But if the site was only indexed slightly longer than 6 months ago and there are other sub pages with a PR of 6, then we can safely assume that while we're not in real time there is probably something going on with regard to the homepage, no?

Comment: I understand toolbars are not very reliable in terms of defining the page rank, however, since launching the website the same toolbar showed change in pagerank for internal pages, and no change whatsoever for the home page - this is what bugs me. As to sales and advertising info on the home page, we don't have such - the content on the home page is product-related, however, informational rather than sales. The webamster tools account also says everything is ok..

Comment: Possibly. Just because the toolbar says 0 doesn't mean it is zero. The toolbar has been known to displayed zero for lots of pages that really weren't a zero PR. If the page ranks well then it's probably just a reporting issue. If it ranks poorly then you have a real issue.

Comment: @ binaryorganic - yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: The page performs not too bad in terms of organic positions, which possibly might mean it's a reporting issue. Thank you!

Comment: Bingo!  Sometimes it's easy to forget that PR is just a number that may or may not reflect actual results.  At the end of the day it's the results that matter.

Answer (score 2):

The PR cycle is a bit mysterious, but it's been suggested that PR changes are usually visible somewhere in the midst of a 90 day cycle.

The fact that your sub pages have page rank means that the PR of zero on the home page is quite likely accurate (i.e. it's not an issue of waiting for Google).  If that is indeed the case you need to look at why your subpages have high page rank.  Are there a lot of external links coming in to these pages?  Is there a specific keyword string you've been ranking well for on those pages?  Compare all the pros and the cons between the pages on your domain that are ranking well and those that aren't and you'll hopefully get some insight.