# Why Google not ranking my websites..?

Tags: seo, pagerank, google-ranking, google-index

Please observe http://www.panbeli.in and http://www.softwaregenius.net

Why is this site does not get ranked by Google Spider? It has been
grayed in Google Tool Bar for a while. Google has the knowledge of it.
You can search for http://www.panbeli.in and http://www.softwaregenius.net
and you will see the both websites in google search,yahoo search,bing search,
you found that we have lots of backlinks also ,http://www.panbeli.in alexa rank is 695,295
and http://www.softwaregenius.net alexa rank is 994,219.

we have also created Blogs/News/Classified/google ADsence/press relese etc to increase the
rang for http://www.panbeli.in and http://www.softwaregenius.net websites.

When i check my SEO statistics using different SEO tools, it shows Google backlink is zero.

however, Google just does not want to rank it. Can you tell me why?
Why is it penalized? I have tried to do my best to clean it. Your
kind reply is appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Irfan

Comment: *panbeli.in alexa rank is 695,295 and softwaregenius.net alexa rank is 994,219* : Alexa rankings mean nothing in this context and even if they did, these ranks are not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll point to John C's answer here: [How long does it take for a page to be assigned Google page rank?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-page-to-be-assigned-google-page-rank)

> Public PR is updated only periodically so whatever PR you see via reporting tools is a snapshot of the past. It does not reflect a page's current PR.

So to paraphrase - don't worry if google toolbar doesn't show a page ranking, as it isn't a real time reflection of your pagerank.

Open a webmasters tools account with google if you don't have one already, if anything is wrong with your site google will let you know here.

Just a friendly pointer - http://softwaregenius.net took quite a long time to load up (almost 10 seconds), it might be worth looking at the number of scripts you use or the nesting of tables for layout.